# Android TV application display over other apps permission

Tags: android, android-tv

I am using "TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY" and "TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY" parameters in WindowManager class in android TV application.

This activty also needs some permissions

`<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />`

I tried the application on STB and just open the display over other app permission on the settings, then it works.

When ı install the app Android TV this permission not include in settings. How is the open this permission on Android TV (android version 8) ?

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: Thank you for interest @abielita I found the solutions for this problem https://github.com/muhammetaslan/Android-errors-and-solutions-